# Runtime Compilation, System.Drawing.Graphics not found

Tags: vb.net, exception, reflection, compilation, system.drawing

I am trying to compile a piece of Code at Runtime with the VBCodeProvider class.
It works great with one exception. I can't access any members of the System.Drawing
Namespace.
I do an "Imports System.Drawing" at the beginning of the code which does
compile without an error (so I guess the reference is there alright) but when I try
to define for example a graphics object with "Dim g as Graphics" or "Dim g as System.Drawing.Graphics" I get an exception on compilation: `{[...] error BC30002: Der Typ "Graphics" ist nicht definiert. (The type Graphics is not defined)}`

When I try to add the System.Drawing.dll to the ReferencedAssemblies of the CompilerOptions then I get a whole bunch of other compilation errors so I guess that's not the solution.
I don't really get why this problem is there. For example in the same code I use members of System.Math which work.

Does anyone have an idea or tip for me of what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.
Jens

edit due to lack of reputation:

Thank you for your help. Typical thing: You try and search for over an hour, then you ask here and 10 minutes later you find the solution yourself:

The problem was with how I referenced the system.drawing.dll in the compileroptions. I did use an absolute path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll" and that gave me 19 exceptions in some code I did not even write myself.!

[image]

What worked was to use a relative path. e.g.

PM.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll")

I don't know what the real difference is, but at least this works. :-)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you show some code where you try to use `Graphics` (edit the post)?

Comment: Show the other errors you get after adding System.Drawing assembly.

Comment: Other assemblies also have a System.Drawing namespace so that doesn't mean anything.  Of course you need to add the reference, the "whole bunch of errors" are of course essential to diagnose the root problem.

Comment: If you have found the solution, please add that as an answer and mark that answer as accepted. Otherwise, future readers will always see the question as open, i.e. as unsolved.

Comment: I have an 8 hour delay between the original post and the time I can answer the thread myself. Therefore I have done the edit. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical thing: You try and search for over an hour, then you ask here and 10 minutes later you find the solution yourself:

The problem was with how I referenced the system.drawing.dll in the compileroptions. I did use an absolute path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll` and that gave me 19 exceptions in some code I did not even write myself.

[image: See in image here]

What worked was to use a relative path. e.g.

```
PM.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll")
```

I don't know what the real difference is, but at least this works.